# What is the difference of defining a vector field on a manifold and a $C^{k-1}$ vector field on a $C^{k}$ manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

In definition number 6.6 [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/cis610-15-sl6.pdf) a $C^{k-1}$ vector field is defined on $C^{k}$ manifold, is this merely to express the dimensionality of a vector field or there is more meaning to $C^{k}$ and $C^{k-1}$?

Answer (score 3):

If $\gamma$ is an integral curve for the $C^{k-1}$ vector field $X$, then $\gamma$ is $C^{k}$ (its derivative is $X,$ which can be differentiated a further $k-1$ times). Thus, for $\gamma$ to exist, you should have a notion of $k$'th derivative.